# jetty ,websockets and UTF8 encoding

Tags: java, javascript, jetty, websocket, embedded-jetty

I'm having a little problem. I'm building a small server in java, based on jetty websockets implementations.
The clients are the browsers and I send information using the websockets javascript api.

Everything works great until I send those special characters such as :  ă Ț î ș ê ñ ü
So here is the problem. Client 1 sends a message to the server with one of this characters. Server prints the message and then send the message to client 2.

Client 2 receives the message and prints the message on a browser html page and works great The characters are showed correctly.

The problem is when I wanna print the String on the server site. Instead of **ă** is shows me the **?** char. This is causing me problems because I want to insert the text in a database(mysql- with ut8 encoding enabled)

So.. what seems to be problem. The text that is send from the browser is not UT8 encoded? or the jetty websocket implementation is not receiving String in utf8 encoding??

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it applies, but I've stumbled up a similar article here which explains how some mimetypes are interpreted as non-UTF8 by default in Jetty:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31854430/3196753

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I use to HTML-encode all special characters in a string (but not html itself (like `<` or `>`)). If you apply it before sending a string to the server, everybody should see the same and you can store it in a database table:

```
function toHtmlEncoded(string){
    return string.replace(/[\u0080-\uC350]/g, 
                      function(a) {return '&#'+a.charCodeAt(0)+';';}
           );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First read this http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Then check everywhere you've converted bytes into Strings (or the reverse). Common places to make a mistake include calling `getBytes()` on a `String` without specifying an encoding. Other pitfalls include not setting the encoding in the database connection string.