# Jetty response character encoding

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, jetty, content-type

How do I set the default character encoding on my responses to UTF-8?

I've tried this

```
    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```

and this

```
    System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset", "utf-8");
```

Neither has any effect - responses are still sent with the header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I'd like to do this for all text/html responses, and ideally in code rather than XML. I'm using Jetty 9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Jetty documentation claims it uses UTF-8 by default, but that seems to be a lie. If you do the normal `response.getWrite().println("Hello")`, then the content encoding is determined as follows.

1. A default mapping from content-type to content-encoding is loaded from `org/eclipse/jetty/http/encoding.properties`:

```
        // MimeTypes.java:155
        ResourceBundle encoding = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org/eclipse/jetty/http/encoding");
        Enumeration<String> i = encoding.getKeys();
        while(i.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String type = i.nextElement();
            __encodings.put(type,encoding.getString(type));
        }
```

The default file is:

```
text/html   = ISO-8859-1
text/plain  = ISO-8859-1
text/xml    = UTF-8
text/json   = UTF-8
```

2. `Response.getWriter()` tries to use that map, but defaults to ISO-8859-1

```
@Override
public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException
{
    if (_outputType == OutputType.STREAM)
        throw new IllegalStateException("STREAM");

    if (_outputType == OutputType.NONE)
    {
        /* get encoding from Content-Type header */
        String encoding = _characterEncoding;
        if (encoding == null)
        {
            encoding = MimeTypes.inferCharsetFromContentType(_contentType);
            if (encoding == null)
                encoding = StringUtil.__ISO_8859_1;
            setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        }
```

So you can see that for `text/html` it doesn't default to UTF-8. I don't think there is a way of changing the default from code. The best you can do is change the `encoding.properties` file to this:

```
text/html   = UTF-8
text/plain  = UTF-8
text/xml    = UTF-8
text/json   = UTF-8
```

But even then if it finds an encoding that isn't in there it will default to ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 3):

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: ***default*** character encoding

Answer (score 2):

It matter when you use Writer();

For me If I write

```
resp.getWriter().println("Return");
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

I won't work

But if I change the sequence

```
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
resp.getWriter().println("Return");
```

It will be alright

Comment: The charset needs to be set before `getWriter()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

I created character encoding filter to one legacy application.

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(req instanceof Request){             
            req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

In web.xml filter-mapping has the url-pattern of /*. This routes all requests from the web application through the CharacterEncodingFilter.

```
<filter>
    <display-name>CharacterEncoding</display-name>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.app.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Why did you set the reqests character encoding to utf-8? I think it should be on the response object.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the default `UTF-8` charset to `ISO-8859-1` for example.
The documentation does not make it very clear which parameter name for versions later than 9.3.
Before 9.3 it was `org.eclipse.jetty.util.URI.charset`
For new versions it has been changed to `org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset`
Here's an example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.15.v20190215</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertiesFile>src/main/config/jetty/encode.properties</systemPropertiesFile>
        <jettyXml>src/main/config/jetty/jetty-env.xml</jettyXml>
    </configuration>    
</plugin>
```

content for encode.properties

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: This is for URI / URL encoding. We're talking about >>content<< encoding...