# What does -Dfile.encoding = UTF-8 do in JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: java, file, utf-8, jetty-9, file-encodings

Any idea what does **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** in

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

do? 
I have this option in my jetty server configuration.

If i dont have it, what might be consequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jetty response character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804805/jetty-response-character-encoding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sets a property which defines in which encoding will Java save and read files by default. It must be set at JVM startup.

There are multiple encodings - ways to represent characters on computers. UTF-8 is one of the best to use, as it contains all special characters in many languages.

Once you don't have this property, Java might save files in a different encoding which might lead to strange characters when opening the file with text editor. You can avoid this issue by manually setting the desired encoding to your `OutputStream`s.

Comment: It sets default encoding for both properties. This can be overridden on runtime.