# ActiveMQ REST DELETE call unable to read multibyte characters

Tags: curl, utf-8, jetty, activemq-classic, multibyte-characters

I'm using Apache ActiveMQ 5.16 and simply trying to send data with multibyte characters (e.g. `日一国会ABC`) to a queue using ActiveMQ web console. I'm using CURL call to read the data but response has data as `????ABC`. Can someone point me to what might be the issue?

Data in the ActiveMQ web console:

[image]

`curl` call:

```
curl -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -u username:password \
  "http://localhost:8161/api/message/standalone.source.queue"
```

Response:

[image]

Comment: As part of curl response. I can share that screenshot also and attach there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is activemq uses jetty internally which by default forces encoding as **ISO-8859-1** for the calls. Because of this the characters are not encoded properly. As a fix rebuilt jetty-http jar by setting encoding to **UTF-8** and place it at the existing jar's location of activemq. It should work!!!.

Check the answer of **Timmmm** from this post [Jetty response character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804805/jetty-response-character-encoding).

*If someone knows how to fix it using some application property or web.xml attribute, please do share in comments. Tried multiple options but nothing worked*